# Dependency Conflicts in Riak Core with rebar

Tags: erlang, rebar

I am trying to build an app that is based on riak_core, the problem is that the dependency graph seems to have conflicts.

https://github.com/zkessin/riak_sets/blob/master/rebar.config

The problem seems to be that riak_core includes exometer_core, which includes folsom, and the tag and required version do not match. Is there a way to tell rebar to ignore that?

Comment: What version of rebar are you using? I had a similar problem until I upgraded to rebar 2.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Found out you can use rebar with --force to fix this, rebar 3 will also fix this without that